# Diskless NetBoot images served from a 10.8/10.9 server will not consistently boot

Tags: macos, netboot

When hosting a diskless Netboot image from a server running 10.8/10.9 (I have witnessed this with both) the client machine will frequently not boot giving an error:

mount_afp: AFPMountURL returned error 1, error is 3
waiting for local drives (retry 1/10)...

When hosting the same image from a 10.6 server I never get this error. The image can be 10.9 or 10.6...does not matter. If the client is restarted it may boot normally the second try or may take several attempts to finally boot normally.

The rc.netboot file is configured for "Netboot-only" yet it still goes through the process of looking for local drives before it shuts down. From what I can find the error points to not finding a network volume to write the shadow file to????

The issue is not the image, but the version of server the image is hosted from and/or some configuration I am missing on my 10.9 server that causes the AFP share not to respond correctly? Maybe because server in 10.8/10.9 is not the same as 10.6 (separate OS)???

Any thoughts?...I'm currently having to keep 10.6 servers on line to host my 10.9 images because of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading the 10.9 boot servers to 10.9.2 seemed to fix the problem. I have not witnessed the error since the upgrade.